# How to update table from form laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Hey Guys im trying to have this form update my `users table` but im not sure how to do it in laravel. Here is my form

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile/update">
    <div class="form-group hidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $user->id;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email"><b>Name:</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Please enter your email here" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $user->name;?>"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email"><b>Email:</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Please enter your email here" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $user->email;?>"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> Submit </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Update user profile & make backend push to DB
    **/

    public function index() {

        // connecting to the DB and accessing
        $user = Auth::user();
        //var_dump($user);
        return view('profile', compact('user'));

    }

    public function update(Request $request) {

        $request->only('name','email');
        return back();
    }
}
```

my `update method` will handle the input but im not sure what to do from here.

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

First off: I wouldn't recommend `echo`ing the properties of `$user`. Use the Blade syntax, e.g. `{{ $user->id }}`. For the sake of security, [Laravel Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade) escapes your values when you use this syntax.

Check out the [Laravel documentation on inserting & creating models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models) for more information about creating a model.

Essentially, what you'll want to do is something along the lines of this:

```
public function update(Request $request) {

    $input = $request->only('name','email');

    $user = Auth::user(); // Fetch the user model

    // Update the fields
    $user->name = $input['name'];
    $user->email = $input['email'];

    // Save changes
    $user->save();

    return back();
}
```

Comment: so let me get this straight. for best practices i would just pass all this data to a model?

Comment: Usually there's some validation beforehand, either [within the controller method itself](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) or using [form request validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation). There's a couple way of doing things but [check out this video](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/10) on updating records.